# Extracting hash from the url bar after loading the link

Tags: javascript

Let say I have a html page with a link like [click here](https://google.com#123123).

I want that when a user clicks the link and the link opens in the bar I want to extract that hash value.

Comment: You cannot do it with only JavaScript because the script needs to execute on the target site to capture its URL hash.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var hashValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Comment: Hi there. I tried that but it executes before the link opens in the url bar.

Comment: if you are trying to extract it from a external page, you can't. The script has to be on the page itself.